# How do I install Ubuntu if the installer can't locate the hard drive?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Let me start from the beginning. My Windows 7 failed. So I thought it would be good time to install Ubuntu. I created a bootable USB drive to make thing easy because the boot sector on my computer is where the problem had originally occurred.

I tried getting 13.10 but it was freezing when I would get to the Installation screen. My next thought was to try an earlier version. So now I have a bootable USB drive with 12.04 on it.

Now, when I get to the Install screen, it does not detect the hard drive at all. I am running a Toshiba Satellite L505D. The error message I am receiving is :

```
No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu.
```

The problem is, there is nothing to select it from. I am unable to create a new partition, add, change, delete or revert because there is nothing to select in the above menu.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you using the 64 bit version?
2. Are you making the USB stick bootable? Just putting the .iso on there does not work. You need to use something like universal pen drive to make it bootable.
3. Also, you may need to hold down option, command, CTL, ect, at the time of boot to select your boot drive. It may also be an F12 key, I'm not sure with your exact computer but Google how to choose drive at boot.

Comment: 1. Yes, I am using the 64 bit version.

Comment: 2.I did make the USB drive bootable. I used the PenDrive program. 3. I chose the usb drive to boot from. However, I will try again.

Comment: I assume your machine is 64 bit, but you should check if your machine is bootable in any OS. If your HD is blank, make the bootable USB or DVD and you can select "try ubuntu". It makes no changes to your computer but you could see what might be wrong with your HD by using Gparted. It is a partitioning tool. If you are very new to Ubuntu I would be happy to guide you through installing it.

Comment: Good, so the drive is bootable. Now, when you boot your machine, try and stop it at the bios and choose to boot from USB instead of the internal HD.

Comment: Ok. I manually selected the USB to boot from. And yes I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you trying to dual boot with windows 7? Or do you just want Ubuntu? Because the way in which you went about partitioning the HD would be very different.

Comment: If I can keep the windows files that would be great, if not, then oh well.

Comment: I clicked on try Ubuntu.

Comment: GREAT! Happy to help new users. I'll walk you through step by step, I'm searching for a guide I could link you. Give me just a second. Keep me updated on what's happening an if you want to dual boot or single boot.

Comment: I want to try and dual boot first.

Comment: Is Windows 7 the first part of the disk? If yes, does it work?

Comment: Windows 7 does not currently work because of the bad boot sector on the hard drive. that much I have figured out

Comment: Ok. So I found the Gparted program and the only deice it found was the USB drive.

Comment: Use the thread above this one.

Comment: What thread are you referring to?

Comment: Nvm, it just keeps telling me that this one has reached it's limit. I answered another question. It should be on this page.

Comment: Ok so the windows boot sector is bad. Have you already tried to install ubuntu? Is that what damaged it? or was it already damaged?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it made me stop using the original thread because it was too long, but I cannot yet move to chat mode. So we can just use this thread now.

Comment: Ok so the windows boot sector is bad. Have you already tried to install ubuntu? Is that what damaged it? or was it already damaged?

Comment: Yeah it's showing the USB but you can change the drive by looking in the right hand corner and changing it to the HD. It will scan it but no changes will be made so long as you don't delete anything.

Comment: Ok. Like I said before, he Gparted only detects the USB drive.

Comment: Yeah I kinda have some bad news.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2116403

Comment: One day my computer just stopped working. There is a bad sector on the hard drive an it happens to be in the boot sector. I have already tried to install Ubuntu but the partitioning does not etect the hard drive for some reason.

Comment: Apparently your machine is quite hard to install Ubuntu on. Hopefully someone far more knowledgeable than I can help you. My advice, no matter what, try and fix windows first. That way you don't loose all your data.

Comment: It may not be detecting the HD because of the format type. Ubuntu mostly uses MSDOS or EXT 4.

Comment: Keep your Windows 7 copy, I would not reformat just yet. If you have your Windows install disk try and repair it. Just put in the CD and boot to it just like you did with the USB.

Comment: There should be a repair option that might take care of that boot loader error. Then you can move on to installing something like refit and partitioning, but without a healthy Windows copy I would not continue unless you are ok with loosing everything.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think it wasn't just the hard drive, it could be a problem with the motherboard reading the hard drive. if that's the case, I just need a new computer.

Comment: Ah, I see. But, if you have your original Windows 7 CD you could run repair disk. Then save a ton of money.

Comment: I will exhaust every option I can before I do that. Thank you so much for your help. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: Either way, I hope it works out for you. If you need any help at all, just post in here again and I will see it. I love helping people switch to any form of linux.

Comment: Anytime.

Happy Holidays.